# How to reply message with a list of button options in whatsapp web.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, chatbot

```
const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia, Buttons } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal')
const axios = require('axios');
const images = require('./data')
const fs = require('fs');
const WwebjsSender = require('@deathabyss/wwebjs-sender')



const quotes = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://type.fit/api/quotes'
};


const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
});


client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true })
});


client.on('authenticated', () => {
    console.log('Authenticated');
});

let chatId = ""
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.body);
    chatId = message.from;
    console.log(chatId);
});


//buttons
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.body == "!command") {
        const from = chatId
        console.log(from);
        let embed = new WwebjsSender.MessageEmbed()
            .sizeEmbed(28)
            .setTitle("✅ | Successful process!")
            .setDescription("The process has been successful!")
            .addField("✔", "To confirm")
            .addField("❌", "To cancel")
            .addFields({
                name: "Now you have 2 buttons",
                value: "✔ or ❌",
            })
            .setFooter('WwebjsSender')
            .setTimestamp();

        let button1 = new WwebjsSender.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("confirm")
            .setLabel("✔")

        let button2 = new WwebjsSender.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("cancel")
            .setLabel("❌");

        try {
            WwebjsSender.send({
                client: client,
                number: from,
                embed: embed,
                button: [button1, button2]
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
});

//Listen for incoming messages

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Client is ready");
});


client.initialize();
```

I am building a bot using whatsapp-web.js. I want to send send buttons as replies.
I made confirm that I am authenticated. I tried many ways to get buttons as replies but none of them is working.
I am using @deathabyss/wwebjs-sender to get buttons in the bot.
But I am not getting any replies or errors.

Show me a way to send buttons as replies in whatsapp-web.js?

Answer (score 0):

have you seen [this reference](https://codingislove.com/send-list-options-get-user-response-whatsapp-api/)

```js
const { Client, LocalAuth, Buttons, List } = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");
 
const myGroupName = "Source Group";
 
const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
});
 
client.on("qr", (qr) => {
  qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});
 
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");
  client.getChats().then((chats) => {
    myGroup = chats.find((chat) => chat.name === myGroupName);
 
    const productsList = new List(
      "Here's our list of products at 50% off",
      "View all products",
      [
        {
          title: "Products list",
          rows: [
            { id: "apple", title: "Apple" },
            { id: "mango", title: "Mango" },
            { id: "banana", title: "Banana" },
          ],
        },
      ],
      "Please select a product"
    );
    client.sendMessage(myGroup.id._serialized, productsList);
  });
});
 
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.type === 'list_response'){
    message.reply(`You've selected ${message.body}`);
  }
});
 
client.initialize();
```

maybe the [List](https://docs.wwebjs.dev/List.html) and [Buttons](https://docs.wwebjs.dev/Buttons.html) from `const { Client, LocalAuth, Buttons, List } = require("whatsapp-web.js");` have a reference of how to use it.